# i want to create table with php variable + name

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

i want to create table with php variable+ name 
like.

here is my code

```
   if($conn->query($sql1)===TRUE){ 
 $_SESSION['username'] = $x;
 $sql = "CREATE TABLE $x
 (
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
image blob,
date datetime,
status longtext,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)";

 $sql2 = "CREATE TABLE ".$x."_frnd
 (
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
myfrndname varchar(255),
myfrndusername varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
 )";
  $result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql,$sql2);

  if ($conn->query($result) === TRUE) {

    }
```

here ($x) is a variable and frnd is mannual name-
i want result table like this.
[ adminfrnd ].
please suggest me.

Comment: Side note: creating a brand new table for each user is a design pattern that will cause you endless headaches in the next years (trust me!). I strongly recommend that you maintain *one* table and add some `user_id` column.

Comment: BTW, does this question have anything to do with PhpMyAdmin? Are you creating a plugin for this application?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$x}frnd` (
  `id` mediumint(6) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `myfrndname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `myfrndlastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `myfrndusername` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

by the way

Why do you want to make own table for each admin ?

Comment: actually i want to excute 2 query in one time ..i want to create 2 table in one sql query....i have update my code ..please check it again

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to append text like this:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $x . "frnd
( ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  myfrndname varchar(255), 
 myfrndlastname varchar(255), 
 myfrndusername varchar(255), 
 PRIMARY KEY (ID) )";
```

Comment: actually i want to excute 2 query in one time ..i want to create 2 table in one sql query....i have update my code ..please check it again

Comment: It's quite easy, append the second table code at the end of the first like this: `$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $x . "frnd
( ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  myfrndname varchar(255), 
 myfrndlastname varchar(255), 
 myfrndusername varchar(255), 
 PRIMARY KEY (ID) ); CREATE TABLE " . $x . "_perms ( blah blah blah);";`

Answer (score 0):

**In your example `$x` should be string.**

Your code will look like:

```
$x="admin";
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$x."_frnd
    ( ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      myfrndname varchar(255), 
     myfrndlastname varchar(255), 
     myfrndusername varchar(255), 
     PRIMARY KEY (ID) )";
    $result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);  
    if ($conn->query($result) === TRUE) {
    }
```

Note: its never good habit to use `.`(dot) in table name use `_`(underscore) instead

Comment: actually i want to excute 2 query in one time ..i want to create 2 table in one sql query....i have update my code ..please check it again

Comment: @kartik use _User_ table to keep track of users. Don't create new table for each user. This will take you into very bad practice.

Comment: because i want to keep data persnoaly for every user thats why i am creating new table for all user............a

Comment: Sir, this will not effective